# CSS3 Steps Menu Full Width Responsive Arrow

Tags: html, css

I have created a CSS steps with left and right arrows on desktop. On mobile, I want this to look like this:

[image: Goal]

This is what I have so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/06u3bm72/

As you can see, I would like to create full-width top arrows on each list item so that the triangle shape is created, like the design. Is there any way to keep my current markup and achieve this?

My code is:

```css
.breadcrumbs-two {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.breadcrumbs-two {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.breadcrumbs-two li {
  float: left;
  width: 18.3%;
}

.breadcrumbs-two a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.breadcrumbs-two a span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.breadcrumbs-two a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-width: 40px 0 40px 30px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
  left: -30px;
}

.breadcrumbs-two a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #ddd;
  right: -30px;
}

.bread1 a {
  background-color: #8ac43c;
}

.bread1 a::before {
  border-color: #8ac43c #8ac43c #8ac43c transparent;
}

.bread1 a::after {
  border-color: transparent #8ac43c transparent #8ac43c;
}

.bread2 a {
  background-color: #69aa4e;
}

.bread2 a::before {
  border-color: #69aa4e #69aa4e #69aa4e transparent;
}

.bread2 a::after {
  border-color: transparent #69aa4e transparent #69aa4e;
}

.bread3 a {
  background-color: #448e60;
}

.bread3 a::before {
  border-color: #448e60 #448e60 #448e60 transparent;
}

.bread3 a::after {
  border-color: transparent #448e60 transparent #448e60;
}

.bread4 a {
  background-color: #1f7171;
}

.bread4 a::before {
  border-color: #1f7171 #1f7171 #1f7171 transparent;
}

.bread4 a::after {
  border-color: transparent #1f7171 transparent #1f7171;
}

.bread5 a {
  background-color: #005581;
}

.bread5 a::before {
  border-color: #005581 #005581 #005581 transparent;
}

.bread5 a::after {
  border-color: transparent #005581 transparent #005581;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .breadcrumbs-two li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  li.bread1 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two a {
    padding-top: 0;
    background-clip: content-box;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -40px;
    border-width: 40px 0 40px 20px;
    border-width: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px auto 0 auto;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
    display: none;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two a::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -40px;
    right: -20px;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumbs-two">
  <li class="bread1"><a><span><strong>Discovery</strong> and sales audit</span></a></li>
  <li class="bread2"><a><span>Priorities and <strong>Action Plan</strong></span></a></li>
  <li class="bread3"><a><span>Workshops and <strong>Collaborations</strong></span></a></li>
  <li class="bread4"><a><span><strong>Execute</strong> and <strong>Implement</strong></span></a></li>
  <li class="bread5"><a><span><strong>Results</strong> and <strong>Adoption</strong></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is possible using `clip-path` ([check browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)). And with the help of this website: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ (I'm trying to simplify your menu and will post an answer if I can do it)

Comment: For each block, you can use pseudo elements `after` or `before` and then shape it like a triangle (using transparent borders hack) and place it at the bottom so that it overlaps on the next block. Color this arrow accordingly and it will seem to be part of the upper block exactly like the arrow you want. For making the groove in topmost block, you can use similar element with white background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve that using before and after pseudo elements and borders with a transparent color.

Here is an example of how to do it, this can be better optimized but I think it serves you as guide.

https://codepen.io/itscarlosisaac/pen/MOQOZO

```
.breadcrumbs-two{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    .breadcrumbs-two{
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }
.breadcrumbs-two li{
      float: left;
      width: 18.3%;
    }
    .breadcrumbs-two a{
      text-transform: uppercase;
      float: left;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FFF;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 80px;
      line-height: 1.3;
    font-size: 15px;
    }   
    .breadcrumbs-two a span {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 150px;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
    }
    .breadcrumbs-two a::before{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%; 
      margin-top: -40px;   
      border-width: 40px 0 40px 30px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
      left: -30px;
    }
    .breadcrumbs-two a::after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%; 
      margin-top: -40px;   
      border-top: 40px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
      border-left: 30px solid #ddd;
      right: -30px;
    }
    .bread1 a {
        background-color: #8ac43c;
    }
    .bread1 a::before {
        border-color: #8ac43c #8ac43c #8ac43c transparent;
    }
    .bread1 a::after {
        border-color: transparent #8ac43c transparent #8ac43c;
    }
    .bread2 a {
        background-color: #69aa4e;
    }
    .bread2 a::before {
        border-color: #69aa4e #69aa4e #69aa4e transparent;
    }
    .bread2 a::after {
        border-color: transparent #69aa4e transparent #69aa4e;
    }
    .bread3 a {
        background-color: #448e60;
    }
    .bread3 a::before {
        border-color: #448e60 #448e60 #448e60 transparent;
    }
    .bread3 a::after {
        border-color: transparent #448e60 transparent #448e60;
    }
    .bread4 a {
        background-color: #1f7171;
    }
    .bread4 a::before {
        border-color: #1f7171 #1f7171 #1f7171 transparent;
    }
    .bread4 a::after {
        border-color: transparent #1f7171 transparent #1f7171;
    }
    .bread5 a {
        background-color: #005581;
    }
    .bread5 a::before {
        border-color: #005581 #005581 #005581 transparent;
    }
    .bread5 a::after {
        border-color: transparent #005581 transparent #005581;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .breadcrumbs-two{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:visible;
    padding-bottom:40px;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two a span{ top:45px; }
        .breadcrumbs-two li {
            float: none;
            width: 100vw;
    height: 80px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
        }
  .breadcrumbs-two li:first-child:before{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width: 100vw;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    border-top:30px solid white;
    border-left:50vw solid transparent;
    border-right:50vw solid transparent;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    z-index:1;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two li:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width: 100vw;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-30px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    border-left:50vw solid transparent;
    border-right:50vw solid transparent;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
        .breadcrumbs-two a {
            width: 100%;    
        }
        li.bread1 {
    z-index:10;
        }
        li.bread2 {
    z-index:9;
        }
        li.bread3 {
    z-index:8;
        }
        li.bread4 {
    z-index:7;
        }
        li.bread5 {
    z-index:6;
        }
  li.bread1:after{
    border-top:30px solid #8ac43c;
  }
  li.bread2:after{
    border-top:30px solid #69aa4e;
  }
  li.bread3:after{
    border-top:30px solid #448e60;
  }
  li.bread4:after{
    border-top:30px solid #1f7171;
  }
  li.bread5:after{
    border-top:30px solid #005581;
  }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) first**

There are other ways of doing this (maybe background-image?) but I did it with a new technology: `clip-path`

There are some hardcoded numbers that depend on the height of each menu item (check the comments on the code below)

I have also changed your code, but feel free to read it and modify it to your needs.

To get the clip-path code I used [bennettfeely.com/clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

```css
.breadcrumbs-two {
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px; /* hardcoded - (height * 0.25) */
  margin: 0;
  width: 18.3%;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.breadcrumbs-two li {
  display: block;
}

.breadcrumbs-two a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px; /* this is where the height comes from */
  margin-bottom: -20px; /* hardcoded - (height * 0.25) - you can add +1px to hide some "white broder" that may showup between menu items */
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 75%, 50% 100%, 100% 75%, 100% 0, 50% 25%); /* this is where the 0.25 comes from */
}
.breadcrumbs-two a:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.breadcrumbs-two a span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 170px;
  margin-top: 10px; /* hardcoded - ((height * 0.25) / 2) */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bread1 a {
  background-color: #8ac43c;
}
.bread2 a {
  background-color: #69aa4e;
}
.bread3 a {
  background-color: #448e60;
}
.bread4 a {
  background-color: #1f7171;
}
.bread5 a {
  background-color: #005581;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .breadcrumbs-two {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="breadcrumbs-two">
    <li class="bread1">
      <a><span><strong>Discovery</strong> and sales audit</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="bread2">
      <a><span>Priorities and <strong>Action Plan</strong></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="bread3">
      <a><span>Workshops and <strong>Collaborations</strong></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="bread4">
      <a><span><strong>Execute</strong> and <strong>Implement</strong></span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="bread5">
      <a><span><strong>Results</strong> and <strong>Adoption</strong></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Personally, I would just use SVGs for the arrow and not worry about building it through CSS.

Comment: It does have a better browser support and I think would be easier to implement, but maybe not so flexible (because of the heights/paddings/margins - if you change the svg dimensions, you need to remember to change other values in css) - if the image is always the same, I would go for it

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out with [transform: skewY(6deg)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) or -6deg, creating two 50%-width divs as before and after of a tag, place it left and right to the a tag.

https://jsfiddle.net/06u3bm72/1/

Browser [support](https://caniuse.com/#search=skew) goes here.

You can just update the `height: 50%;` and the `width:100%` and the `transform: skewX(xdeg)` and `top/bottom: 0` to make it fix for desktop, too. And 94% of the browser perfectly support for this.

```css
.breadcrumbs-two{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
  }
    .breadcrumbs-two li{
    float: left;
    width: 18.3%;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two a{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 1.3;
     font-size: 15px;
  }   
  .breadcrumbs-two a span {
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 100%;
   width: 150px;
   margin: auto;
   position: relative;
   top: 20px;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two a::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    margin-top: -40px;   
    border-width: 40px 0 40px 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ddd #ddd #ddd transparent;
    left: -30px;
  }
  .breadcrumbs-two a::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    margin-top: -40px;   
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid #ddd;
    right: -30px;
  }
  .bread1 a {
   background-color: #8ac43c;
  }
  .bread1 a::before {
   border-color: #8ac43c #8ac43c #8ac43c transparent;
  }
  .bread1 a::after {
   border-color: transparent #8ac43c transparent #8ac43c;
  }
  .bread2 a {
   background-color: #69aa4e;
  }
  .bread2 a::before {
   border-color: #69aa4e #69aa4e #69aa4e transparent;
  }
  .bread2 a::after {
   border-color: transparent #69aa4e transparent #69aa4e;
  }
  .bread3 a {
   background-color: #448e60;
  }
  .bread3 a::before {
   border-color: #448e60 #448e60 #448e60 transparent;
  }
  .bread3 a::after {
   border-color: transparent #448e60 transparent #448e60;
  }
  .bread4 a {
   background-color: #1f7171;
  }
  .bread4 a::before {
   border-color: #1f7171 #1f7171 #1f7171 transparent;
  }
  .bread4 a::after {
   border-color: transparent #1f7171 transparent #1f7171;
  }
  .bread5 a {
   background-color: #005581;
  }
  .bread5 a::before {
   border-color: #005581 #005581 #005581 transparent;
  }
  .bread5 a::after {
   border-color: transparent #005581 transparent #005581;
  }
     
  @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
      .breadcrumbs-two {
        padding-top: 40px;
      }
      .breadcrumbs-two li {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
   .breadcrumbs-two a {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%; 
        background-color: transparent;
        overflow: visible;
   }
      .breadcrumbs-two a span {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 15%;
        width: 150px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -75px;
   }
      
   .breadcrumbs-two  a::before {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #8ac43c;
        border: 0;
        transform: skewY(6deg);
        top: 30%;
      }
   .breadcrumbs-two  a::after {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #8ac43c;
        border: 0;
        transform: skewY(-6deg);
        top: 30%;
      }
      .breadcrumbs-two .bread1 a::after, .breadcrumbs-two .bread1 a::before {
        background-color: #8ac43c;
      }
      .breadcrumbs-two .bread2 a::after, .breadcrumbs-two .bread2 a::before {
        background-color: #69aa4e;
      }
      .breadcrumbs-two .bread3 a::after, .breadcrumbs-two .bread3 a::before {
        background-color: #448e60;
      }
      .breadcrumbs-two .bread4 a::after, .breadcrumbs-two .bread4 a::before {
        background-color: #1f7171;
      }
      .breadcrumbs-two .bread5 a::after, .breadcrumbs-two .bread5 a::before {
        background-color: #005581;
      }
   /* li.bread1 {
     margin-left: 0;
   }
   .breadcrumbs-two a {
     padding-top:0;
     background-clip:content-box;
     overflow:hidden;
   }
   .breadcrumbs-two a::before{
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%; 
     margin-top: -40px;   
     border-width: 40px 0 40px 20px;
     border-width: 40px 0px 0px 40px;
     border-style: solid;
     left: 50%;
     width: 100%;
     left: 0;
     border: 0;
     z-index: 10;
     height: 10px;
     top: 0;
     margin: 0;
     width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 20px auto 0 auto;
   border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
   display: none;
   }
   .breadcrumbs-two a::after{
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%; 
     margin-top: -40px;   
     right: -20px;
     display: none;
   }
    */
  }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 1040px; max-width: 100%; margin: auto;">
<ul class="breadcrumbs-two">
    <li class="bread1"><a><span><strong>Discovery</strong> and sales audit</span></a></li>
    <li class="bread2"><a><span>Priorities and <strong>Action Plan</strong></span></a></li>
    <li class="bread3"><a><span>Workshops and <strong>Collaborations</strong></span></a></li>
    <li class="bread4"><a><span><strong>Execute</strong> and <strong>Implement</strong></span></a></li>
    <li class="bread5"><a><span><strong>Results</strong> and <strong>Adoption</strong></span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You missed one thing, the text is not in the "middle" (vertically). Other than that I think it is a really good solution.